# in ten minutes / in the next ten minutes

Tags: prepositions, time

1. The bus leaves **in ten** minutes.
2. The bus leaves **in the next ten** minutes.

Do the sentences mean the same thing?

Do they mean that

- The bus leaves immediately after 10 minutes.
- The bus leaves within 10 minutes; maybe after 1 minute, maybe after 2 minutes, ...

Comment: Your comprehension of these expressions is spot on! Well done @Vronsky !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in understanding

> The bus leaves in ten minutes.
>   *the bus leaves ten minutes from now, not before, not after*
>
> The bus leaves in the next ten minutes.
>   *the bus leaves within ten minutes, but no more than ten minutes*