# how to understand the "in' in "I'll see you in fifteen minutes"?

Tags: prepositions, time, future-time

> I'll see you in fifteen minutes

One translator translates it with:

> I'll see you fifteen minutes from now

but another translator translates it to:

> I'll see you within fifteen minutes

seems the first is right.

I want to know the meaning of "in" of "in fifteen minutes" will change with context changing? like the second is right in some situation?

And another confusion: [in ten minutes / in the next ten minutes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105948/in-ten-minutes-in-the-next-ten-minutes). Why does "in the next ten minutes" mean "within ten minutes"? Because of "the" or "next"?

Comment: In this context, _in_ means _after the stated period of time has elapsed_.

Comment: *In this context, **within** means **before** the stated period of time has elapsed.* It makes no difference whether you include ***the next*** before the "period of time" noun phrase.